# `emit ThisHappened` vs `ThisHappened` do we need to write `emit`?

Tags: solidity, events

From my experience you can declare events with capital letter.

eg: `ThisHappened(address user, bytes32 act);`

Then you can call it by just writing: `ThisHappened(user, "ATE_HAMBURGER");`

But recently I saw a contract writing `emit ThisHappened(user, "ATE_HAMBURGER");`

What is the difference? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`emit` was introduced in solidity version 0.4.21 after a long discussion. It just helps you to differentiate between event and function. Code will work same with or without `emit`.

For more detail: https://medium.com/@aniketengg/emit-keyword-in-solidity-242a679b0e1a

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it doesn't compile without `emit` in Solidity 0.4.21 and later.

Comment: In my case, it just throws a deprecation warning on Truffle & Remix if you don't use `emit`